# Javascript create object structure

Tags: javascript, object, closures

I used to write a lot of Javascript, and now I'm just jumping back into it, but it seems like I have lost my mind. I'm trying to create an object using function, and I am doing it just the same way that my online searches suggest I should do. I created this example to show the many ways I have tried.

```
<script>
function a(){
    function b(){};
    this.c = function(){};
    this.d = 0;
    var e = function(){};
    var f = 0;
}
a.g = function(){};
a.prototype.h = function(){};

var a2 = function(){
    function b(){};
    this.c = function(){};
    this.d = 0;
    var e = function(){};
    var f = 0;
}
a2.g = function(){};
a2.prototype.h = function(){};
</script>
```

From what I remember, I should be able to call **a.b()**, **a.c()**, and **a.d**, and likewise for **a2**.

However, when I try to call them, it doesn't work. When I type the variable name in the console, it doesn't even show them as being an option. I can however call **a.g()**. I can't call **a.h()**, but I can call **a.prototype.h()**.

I tried this in chrome, and a few things as well in both firefox and Safari.

As far as I can tell from online tutorials, this is not interacting the way I should be expecting it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b`, `e` and `f` are variables in the scope of the function `a`. They are never exposed outside that function.

`c` and `d` are assigned, *when* `a` is called, to whatever `this` is. If you call `new a()` then it will be the instance of a that is returned.

`g` is a property of `a` directly, so you can call it.

`h` is on the prototype chain so it will appear, like `c` and `d`, on instances of `a` created with `new`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I was missing the 'new' keyword. Makes sense now.